# Proxy requests with play to another service

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to proxy all kinds of requests with different Content-Types. I've came up with:

```
  private def proxy(path: String, req: Request[_]) = {
    proxyRequest(path, req).map { data =>
      wsResponseToPlayResponse(data)
    }
  }

  def proxyRequest(path: String, req: Request[_]): Future[WSResponse] = {
    Logger.debug(s"Method: ${req.method}")
    val request = ws.url(path)
      .withMethod(req.method)
      .withHeaders(req.headers.headers: _*)
      .withBody(req.body.toString)
    request.execute()
  }

  private def wsResponseToPlayResponse(data: WSResponse): Result = {
    val transformHeaders = data.allHeaders.map {
      case (key, values) => (key, values.reduce(_ + _))
    }
    Result(
      ResponseHeader(data.status, transformHeaders),
      Enumerator(data.bodyAsBytes)
    )
  }

  private def genLink(service: String, host: String, port: String, path: String) = path match {
    case "" => s"$host:$port/api/$service"
    case knownPath => s"$host:$port/api/$service/$path"
  }
```

But it doesn't work with Images. So tried doing:

```
  def postImage(ref:String) = Action.async(parse.raw) { req =>
    ws.url(s"$BASE_URL/api/images/$ref").withHeaders(req.headers.headers:_*)
      .post(req.body.asFile)
      .map(wsResponseToPlayResponse)
  }
```

But it's malforming file, because external service is reporting:

```
images_1         | 10:41:36.608 [New I/O worker #4] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.netty.handler.HttpProtocol - 
images_1         | 
images_1         | Request DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
images_1         | POST /v1_1/smoffice/image/upload HTTP/1.1
images_1         | Content-Length: 62234
images_1         | Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Fu-UTwfLaSq-uMupRJ23ln6qi4K-KMrj
images_1         | Connection: keep-alive
images_1         | Host: api.cloudinary.com
images_1         | Accept: */*
images_1         | User-Agent: cld-scala-0.9.9-SNAPSHOT
images_1         | 
images_1         | Response DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
images_1         | HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
images_1         | Cache-Control: no-cache
images_1         | Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
images_1         | Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 10:41:36 GMT
images_1         | Server: cloudinary
images_1         | Status: 400 Bad Request
images_1         | X-Cld-Error: Invalid image file
images_1         | X-Request-Id: 93407c1fab141e2c
images_1         | X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
images_1         | Content-Length: 42
images_1         | Connection: keep-alive
images_1         | 
images_1         | 10:41:36.609 [New I/O worker #4] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.channel.ChannelManager - Adding key: https://api.cloudinary.com:443 for channel [id: 0x58dbfb16, /172.19.0.6:51752 => api.cloudinary.com/52.20.33.251:443]
images_1         | 10:41:36.612 [images-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-460] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Error during processing of request HttpRequest(HttpMethod(POST),http://red-services.isaacloud.com/api/images/event,List(Host: red-services.isaacloud.com, X-Forwarded-For: 91.227.215.2, 172.19.0.8, Connection: close, Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/51.0.2704.79 Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36, Accept-Language: pl-PL, pl;q=0.8, en-US;q=0.6, en;q=0.4, Cookie: admin=%22tajne%22; PLAY_SESSION=19bbf7a2603d4bbff9ebb4620a058dbc4014ec73-login=%7B%22id%22%3A43%2C%22firstName%22%3A%22soi%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22soadmin%40soi.soi%22%7D; SESSION_ID=43, Origin: http://localhost:9001, Referer: http://localhost:9001/, Accept-Encoding: utf-8, Timeout-Access: <function1>),HttpEntity.Strict(multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZXKxaJB7V7ND8hU5; charset=UTF-8,------WebKitFormBoundaryZXKxaJB7V7ND8hU5
images_1         | Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="7.png"
images_1         | Content-Type: image/png
images_1         | 
images_1         | ï¿½PNG
images_1         | 
IHDRï¿½ï¿ï¿½ï¿½>0|      pHYs.#.#xï¿½?v
images_1         | OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexÚSgTSï¿½=ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½BKï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ko RBï¿½ï¿½ï¿½&*!   Jï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½Qï¿½EEÈ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½,
                                                                                                                                   ï¿½
images_1         | ï¿½ï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½{ï¿½kÖ¼ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½>ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
                                                                                                   ï¿½H3Q5ï¿½
                                                                                                             ï¿½Bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.@ï¿½
images_1         | $ï¿½d!sï¿½#ï¿½~<<+"ï¿½ï¿½xï¿½
                                               ï¿½Mï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Bï¿½\ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½tï¿½8ï¿½@zï¿½Bï¿½@Fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½&Sï¿½`ï¿½cbï¿½P-`'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½{[ï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½ eï¿½Dh;ï¿½ï¿½Vï¿½EX0fKï¿½9ï¿½-0IWfHï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
             ï¿½
               0Qï¿½ï¿½){`ï¿½##xï¿½ï¿½Fï¿½W<ï¿½+ï¿½ï¿½*xï¿½ï¿½<ï¿½$9Eï¿½-qWW.(ï¿½I+6aaï¿½@.ï¿½yï¿½2ï¿½4ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½_-ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"bbï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ï«p@ï¿½t~ï¿½ï¿½,/ï¿½ï¿½;ï¿½mï¿½ï¿½%ï¿½h^
                     ï¿½uï¿½ï¿½fï¿½@ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Wï¿½pï¿½~<<Eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Jï¿½B[aï¿½W}ï¿½gï¿½_ï¿½Wï¿½lï¿½~<ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½$ï¿½2]ï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Lï¿½Ï   ï¿½bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½
    ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"ï¿½Ibï¿½X*ï¿½Qqï¿½Dï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2ï¿½"ï¿½Bï¿½)ï¿½%ï¿½ï¿½dï¿½ï¿½,ï¿½>ï¿½5ï¿½j>{ï¿½-ï¿½]cï¿½K'Xtï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½oï¿½ï¿½ï¿½hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½wï¿½ï¿½?ï¿½Gï¿½%ï¿½fIï¿½q^D$.TÊ³?ï¿Dï¿½ï¿½*ï¿½Aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
           ï¿½`6ï¿½B$ï¿½ï¿½BB
images_1         | dï¿½r`)ï¿½ï¿½B(ï¿½Í°*`/ï¿½@4ï¿½Qhï¿½ï¿½p.ï¿½Uï¿½=pï¿½ï¿½ï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½   Aï¿a!Úbï¿½X#ï¿ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½!ï¿½Hï¿½$ ÉQ"Kï¿½5H1Rï¿½T UHï¿½=r9ï¿½\Fï¿½ï¿½;ï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½G1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Q=ï¿½
                                                                                                                                                                                               ï¿½Cï¿½ï¿½7ï¿½Fï¿½
                 ï¿½dt1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½rï¿½=ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½Ð«hÚ>Cï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½3ï¿½l0.ï¿½ï¿½Bï¿½8,   ï¿½cË±"ï¿½
                                                                                                          ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½cÏ±wï¿½Eï¿½ 6wB aAHXLXNï¿½Hï¿½ $4ï¿½    7   ï¿½Qï¿½'"ï¿½ï¿½Kï¿½&ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½b21ï¿½XH,#ï¿½ï¿½/{ï¿½Cï¿½7$ï¿½C2'ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½Tï¿½ï¿½Fï¿½nR#ï¿½,ï¿½ï¿½4H#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½dkï¿½9ï¿½, +Èï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½3ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½[
images_1         | ï¿½b@qï¿½ï¿½Sï¿½(Rï¿½jJï¿½ï¿½4ï¿½eï¿½2AUï¿½ï¿½RÝ¨ï¿½T5ï¿½ZBï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Rï¿½Qï¿½ï¿½4uï¿½9ÍIKï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½hhï¿½iï¿½ï¿½tï¿½ÝNï¿½ï¿½Wï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½w
ï¿½ï¿½Çg(ï¿½gwï¿½ï¿½Lï¿½Óï¿½T071ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½oUX*ï¿½*|ï¿½ï¿½
images_1         | ï¿½Jï¿½&ï¿½Tï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Þª
                                             Uï¿½Uï¿½Tï¿½ï¿½^S}ï¿½FU3Sï¿½ï¿½    Ôï¿½Uï¿½ï¿½Pï¿½Sgï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½gï¿½oT?ï¿½~Yï¿½ï¿½Yï¿½Lï¿½OCï¿½Qï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ 
ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½5ï¿½&ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|v*ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½=ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½9C3J3Wï¿½Rï¿½ï¿½f?ï¿½ï¿½qï¿½ï¿½tN   ï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½~ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½)ï¿½Lï¿½1e\kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Xï¿½Hï¿½Qï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Eï¿½Yï¿½ï¿½Aï¿½J'\'Ggï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Sï¿½SÝ§
images_1         | ï¿½M= ... (61476 bytes total)),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.0))
```

This is probably very hard to reproduce though. Have anyone idea how to make universal proxy function?

Comment: I didn't see any utility in play to do this but the solution would be to retrieve the request body as `Source[ByteString, _]` and sending this with the `wsClient`: `ws.url(...).withBody(source)`. 
Actually `WsClient`may not support a `Source[ByteString]`, you could take a look at the [akka http client](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/client-side/index.html)

Comment: I've used many Akka HTTP client few times but I didn't want to incorporate more external tools than needed. For now I just proxied request with nginx. But that's insecure workaround..